# How to parse variables in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a variable with value `"x: 647, y: 1174"` and I would like to parse them into two separate variables: `${x} = 647` and `${y} = 1174`

Is this possible within Robot Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String library](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-2.1.3/doc/libraries/String.html) will help you.

```
${var}    Set Variable    x: 647, y: 1174
${x}    Fetch From Left    ${var}    ,    # now x should be "x: 674"
${x}    Fetch From Right    ${x}    ${SPACE}    # and now it should be "674"
${y}    Fetch From Right    ${var}    y:${SPACE}
```

Or write a python function that does the same with regex for example.